# React Native context values not updating on navigating back to the same screen

Tags: react-native, react-context

So I have a Overview Screen that contains two materials and their information. By default these materials arent selected, and the user has to press a button to go to the material library --> select the material and go back to the Overview Screen, while the `chosenMaterial` context is set with the correct values.

But, once you are back in the overview screen, the `chosenMaterial` context isn't set yet, resulting in nothing showing. While i could do some hacky `useState` in the `useEffect` in order to force a refresh, this doesn't seem correct to me. How could i enforce react native to get the latest context values upon the screen being focused?

Comment: Please add all relevant code

Answer (score 0):

Use focus event because when you return component is not rendered. More examples in official documentation here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen